# Table View starts with last section in: numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This may look duplicate of this: [numberOfRowsInSection starts with last section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171475/numberofrowsinsection-starts-with-last-section), but the solution provided didn't work from me and it was asked long way back and it was in Objective-C. AFAIK language has nothing to do with it.

**Steps:**

1. Call API
2. Add response to array - 10 results
3. Reload Table
4. `numberOfRowsInSections` gets called.
5. `print("section: \(section)")` in `numberOfRowsInSections` prints

   ```
   section: 9
   section: 0
   section: 1
   section: 2
   section: 3
   section: 4
   section: 5
   section: 6
   section: 7
   section: 8
   ```

It is undesired behaviour since I want to have different number of rows within each section.

Since `numberOfRowsInSections`  decides the number of cell within each section, I count the number of section based upon the certain values in each array.

**Response:**

```
{
    count = 10;
    "post_results" =     (
                {
            attachment = "";
            category = "An Act of Kindness";
            "comments_count" = 5;
            description = xjjxjsj;
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "2016-09-13 08:24:38";
                "comment_id" = 199;
                description = "dddg\n";
                "user_picture" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
                username = testing1;
            };
            "likes_count" = 0;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-13 07:59:17";
            "post_id" = 1866;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = jdjsjsj;
            "upload_type" = 0;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = testing1;
        },
                {
            attachment = "";
            category = "In The News";
            "comments_count" = 6;
            description = "check timing";
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "2016-09-13 10:05:11";
                "comment_id" = 207;
                description = "hdhd\n";
                "user_picture" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
                username = testing1;
            };
            "likes_count" = 0;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-13 07:06:46";
            "post_id" = 1864;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = "new post";
            "upload_type" = 0;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = testing1;
        },
                {
            attachment = "";
            category = "An Act of Kindness";
            "comments_count" = 2;
            description = "timer testing";
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "2016-09-13 10:01:41";
                "comment_id" = 201;
                description = "hddn\n";
                "user_picture" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
                username = testing1;
            };
            "likes_count" = 0;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-13 06:56:36";
            "post_id" = 1862;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = hiii;
            "upload_type" = 0;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = testing1;
        },
                {
            attachment = "";
            category = "An Act of Kindness";
            "comments_count" = 0;
            description = Hloo;
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "";
                "comment_id" = "";
                description = "";
                "user_picture" = "";
                username = "";
            };
            "likes_count" = 0;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-13 06:54:48";
            "post_id" = 1860;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = testing;
            "upload_type" = 0;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = testing1;
        },
                {
            attachment = "";
            category = "Making a Difference";
            "comments_count" = 0;
            description = TestContentdfdf899;
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "";
                "comment_id" = "";
                description = "";
                "user_picture" = "";
                username = "";
            };
            "likes_count" = 0;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-13 06:54:14";
            "post_id" = 1858;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = TestTitleerer899;
            "upload_type" = 0;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = max57;
        },
                {
            attachment = "/uploads/2016/09/Koala6-440x330.jpg";
            category = "Making a Difference";
            "comments_count" = 0;
            description = TestContentdfdf89;
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "";
                "comment_id" = "";
                description = "";
                "user_picture" = "";
                username = "";
            };
            "likes_count" = 0;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-13 06:49:07";
            "post_id" = 1855;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = TestTitleerer89;
            "upload_type" = 1;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = max57;
        },
                {
            attachment = "www.praizbuk.com";
            category = "An Act of Kindness";
            "comments_count" = 0;
            description = "";
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "2016-09-13 08:16:01";
                "comment_id" = 194;
                description = "jddj\n";
                "user_picture" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
                username = testing1;
            };
            "likes_count" = 1;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-09 07:12:44";
            "post_id" = 1846;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = db;
            "upload_type" = 3;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = kkk;
        },
                {
            attachment = "/uploads/2016/09/dummy3.mp4";
            category = "An Act of Kindness";
            "comments_count" = 1;
            description = xbbdbd;
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "2016-09-09 07:17:36";
                "comment_id" = 192;
                description = "uugh\n";
                "user_picture" = "/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
                username = kkk;
            };
            "likes_count" = 1;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-09 06:19:20";
            "post_id" = 1842;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = zyhh;
            "upload_type" = 2;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = kkk;
        },
                {
            attachment = "/uploads/2016/09/dummy2.mp4";
            category = "In The News";
            "comments_count" = 0;
            description = "new video uploaded";
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "";
                "comment_id" = "";
                description = "";
                "user_picture" = "";
                username = "";
            };
            "likes_count" = 0;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-09 05:49:48";
            "post_id" = 1838;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = "my video";
            "upload_type" = 2;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = kkk;
        },
                {
            attachment = "";
            category = "An Act of Kindness";
            "comments_count" = 0;
            description = Vdfdfdfdfd;
            "last_comment" =             {
                "comment_date" = "";
                "comment_id" = "";
                description = "";
                "user_picture" = "";
                username = "";
            };
            "likes_count" = 0;
            "post_date" = "2016-09-08 12:00:24";
            "post_id" = 1836;
            "share_count" = "";
            title = fff;
            "upload_type" = 0;
            "user_image" = "/uploads/2016/09/popup-40x40.png";
            "user_name" = kkk;
        }
    );
    status = ok;
}
```

And Table View method is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let post = arrPost[section]
    let comment = post.last_comment

    print("section: \(section)")

    if post.upload_type! == "0" {
        if let _ = comment!.comment_id {
            return 2
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    } else {
        if let _ = comment!.comment_id {
            return 3
        } else {
            return 2
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is it causing issue for you?

Comment: If you have correctly implemented UITableViewDataSource delegate it should work regardless which section is requested first. An issue is somewhere in your code, if you will post it maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @Larme - update the question?

Comment: Could you add an issue description? What exactly does not work?

Comment: I think it has been asked before (not the one that you linked) and people said that it's normal and always like that, i also don't know why it's matter be cause before you reload, you should have your data source ready, not generate while reloading?

Comment: I am rechecking everything I did in my code and will let you know if there's any issue from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issues with the response parameters type.

Final Conclusion as @Avt said in comments:

> *If correctly implemented UITableViewDataSource/delegate it should work regardless which section is requested first.*