# numberOfRowsInSection repeats counting the last section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Possible duplicate : [Table View starts with last section in: numberOfRowsInSection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467461/table-view-starts-with-last-section-in-numberofrowsinsection)
[numberOfRowsInSection starts with last section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171475/numberofrowsinsection-starts-with-last-section?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My number of section code :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

 //   NSLog(@"outsideindx%d", indexsection);
    for (int indexsection = 0 ;  indexsection < [arrayOfArrays count ]  ; indexsection ++)
    {

        NSLog(@"outsidesection%d",section);

        if([buttonTags containsObject:@(section)])
        {
            if (section == indexsection)
            {
                 NSLog(@"HIDING!");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
             return [arrayOfArrays [indexsection] count];
            }

        }

      else
          if(section == indexsection)
        {
            //stars with 1 to 0
            return [arrayOfArrays [indexsection] count];
        }
    }
}
```

What my code does it hides buttons in my header.
buttonTags is an array that contains button that is clicked.
so what i want to do is to hide button that is being clicked.
if the value of  buttonTag is button[1], then the section == 1 will be hidden.

if the buttonTags contains  [ 0 , 1] then the section 0  and 1 will be hidden.

but the result is ruining the idea of my code
the result starts with 1, where i clicked the button [0].

The result is  like this:

```
insidesection: 1
insidesection: 1
insidesection: 0
outsidesection: 1
outsidesection: 0
```

The section result is different from the posted duplicates,

My number of sections is here:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
  //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
  // Return the number of sections.
  return 2;
}
```

What I need to start the counting of section from 0 to 1. not 1 to 0.

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection code is not comple

Comment: @RajeshKumarR edited,

Comment: 1. There is no reason you should care what order `numberOfRowsInSection` is called. 2. Why do you have a `for` loop in `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: Where is return statement in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: @rmaddy updated the post

Comment: @RajeshKumarR updated the post

Comment: My comments still stand. Why do you have a loop in `numberOfRowsInSection`? And why do you care what order `numberOfRowsInSection` is called?

Comment: @rmaddy i need to have loop inside of rowsInsection because i need to check which section i'm modifying. so section == indexsection(1) this stands for that i'm modifying section 1.

Comment: @rmaddy would it possible to determine which section you are modifying without using section == 1? , section  == 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you just want to look at the relevant section rather than looping through all the sections.  Something like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if([buttonTags containsObject:@(section)]) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return [arrayOfArrays[section] count];
    }
}
```